# Read from dataset in HDF5 file with datatype detection

Tags: c, hdf5, hdf

I currently try to read some data from a hdf5 dataset in C which looks like this.

```
dataset = H5Dopen(ic_group, 'vx', H5P_DEFAULT);
status = H5Dread(dataset, H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT, memspace,H5S_ALL,
                          H5P_DEFAULT, vx_ptr);

status = H5Dclose(dataset);
```

Here `ic_group` is a group containing the dataset `vx`, memspace is a hyperslab in memory and vx_ptr the data in memory. This approach works good, however since I want to work with different datatypes later, I want to read the type directly from the dataset:

```
hid_t datatype;
datatype = H5Dget_type(dataset);
status = H5Dread(dataset, datatype, memspace,H5S_ALL,
                          H5P_DEFAULT, vx_ptr);
```

Unfortunately this approach leads to a segfault in the function `H5Dread` .
Maybe I am missing something? Thank you for any suggestions.

EDIT: I don't know if this is usefull but the backtrace of gdb goes down to
`0x00007ffff5adbd1e in __memcpy_ssse3_back () from /lib64/libc.so.6` .

Comment: Are you checking the status values you store assiduously?  If not, how do you know where the failure is first being reported?

Comment: I printed the status values and got 0 in return everytime so this should be Ok. Also I had a look at the datatype id which is i.e.50331962 (after casting to an int) the documentation says that a non negative value in return of `H5Dget_type` is a successfull operation. I debugged the program with GDB so I know that the segfault happens in H5Dread (see edit)

Comment: OK; that is good to know.  It is probably worth saying that you're showing abbreviated code but that error checking in the full code is showing no problem before the crash.  You have checked what value is returned from `H5Dget_type()`, etc...yes, you said you're doing error checking.  What type is returned?  What happens when you hard-code that type into the `H5Dread()` call?

Comment: The return type is hid_t which is an Id to some kind of datatype object but Im not sure how to get access to it.

Comment: I downloaded the HDF5 source code and compiled it; there were a depressingly large number of warnings generated (I was compiling with GCC 4.9.1 on an Ubuntu 14.04 derivative).  Some of the warnings were just unnecessary; others not so clearly unnecessary (I'm worried about them).  Few open source projects generate so many warnings with a default compilation; it worries me.  It is going to take me time to learn enough to use HDF5 properly; I'm not sure whether I'm willing to spend that time on the task given that I'm not about to use HDF5.

Comment: This could be a mismatch between the datatypes used to read and write the dataset. You can use `H5Tequal()` to check that `H5Dget_type(dataset)` is the same as the datatype used to write the data. You may also need to check the datatype of `memspace` too with `H5Sget_select_type()`.

Comment: Ok, I got the error thanks to H5Tequal, thank you! Actually this was a problem when creating different datasets, one was created by accident as type `float64` so this error affected just one dataset causing a segfault. In the whole programm. Maybe you can post this somehow as an Answer and I will give you an upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that the datatype returned from `H5Dget_type(dataset)` is what you expect by using `H5Tequal(datatype, H5T_<type>)`. It should match both the datatype used to write the dataset and also the equivalent type of `vx_ptr` (this is probably what's actually caused the segfault).

Also, `datatype` needs to be closed with `H5Tclose(datatype)`.